# Make pagination little better Vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend

Hello all I created simple vuejs app and deployed to Heroku. Here is url of app:
https://vueappblog.herokuapp.com/. I'm trying to achieve when user clicks any number in pagination (or next button) to back that user to top of the posts list. See image below:

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: try to look into [pagination NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pagination)

Comment: @HarshPatel I'm using: https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll the page to the top after every click using 
window.scrollTo(0,0); method.